# occasional *** stack smashing detected*** with c++

Tags: c++, coredump

I have following C++ code for bubble sort.
This code compiles without any error, but when I re compile and run, I get

> *** stack smashing detected ***: terminated

As a C++ newby I want to know ,why do I get these occasional errors when it runs?

```
void bubbleSort(int eatenPanCakes[10],int arrSize){
 
    int temp=0;
    for(int i=0;i<arrSize-1;i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < arrSize-i; j++)
        {
            if (eatenPanCakes[j] > eatenPanCakes[j+1])
            {
                temp = eatenPanCakes[j+1];
                eatenPanCakes[j+1] = eatenPanCakes[j];
                eatenPanCakes[j] = temp;
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Environment : `g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0`

There is a bug in my code : `for (int j = 0; j+1 < arrSize-i; j++)` would be the right algorithm and that works without error.

[Ref-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61115393/stack-smashing-detected-unknown-terminated-aborted-core-dumped-erro),[Ref-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345670/stack-smashing-detected)

Comment: What’s `arrSize-i` in the first iteration of the outer loop?

Comment: you can use `std::swap` in the inner loop.

Comment: We'll need more code to be certain (like how you call your function). But the "stack smashing" looks like you're trying to access an out-of-bounds element of the passed array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You program is accessing array beyond its size which is an undefined behavior. Check this `for` loop condition:

```
for (int j = 0; j < arrSize-i; j++)
```

*[I believe, `arrSize` value is `10` as the type of `eatenPanCakes` array is `int [10]`]*.

when `i` is `0`, `arrSize-i` value is `10` and in last iteration when `j` value is  `9`, this statement

```
if (eatenPanCakes[j] > eatenPanCakes[j+1])
```

access `j+1`<sup>th</sup> element of `eatenPanCakes` array which is element at index `10`. Note that an array of size `10` will have valid index from `0` to `9`.
Instead, the condition in `for` loop should be

```
for (int j = 0; j < arrSize - i - 1; j++)
                                ^^^
```

because the `j`<sup>th</sup> element is compared with element ahead of it in the array.

Comment: Yes, thanks for detailed explanation. But my problem is, this happens **occasionally**. Sometimes, it runs without `coredump`

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram This is due to undefined behaviour. An undefined behaviour includes it may execute incorrectly (either crashing or silently generating incorrect results), or it may fortuitously do exactly what the programmer intended.